# Page Refresh Causes Duplicate POST in ASP.NET Applications

Tags: asp.net

i have an application in which i am adding a new record and the record is added two times if i am pressing refresh button.

I am clearing the cache but i am having the same problem.
what to do?

Comment: not enough information to help you

Comment: This must have been asked and answered many times in the past, but I had trouble finding the other questions. I've rewritten the title so that this question may be found in the future. I hope Annie and the Community don't mind.

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Answer (score 12):

Once you have handled a post back to a page, best practice is to then redirect so that you can't have the data posted a second time using the "refresh" button. This is common to all web develoment, not just ASP.NET.

Comment: But by doing that we are making an unnecessary server trip. Is there no other approach to avoid that .

Comment: Lesser of two evils, I guess.

Comment: FYI - the design pattern to avoid this is called the Post/Redirect/Get pattern.

Answer (score 8):

My method is shamelessly stolen from page 4 of [this](http://aspalliance.com/687) awesome article on ASP Alliance. To detect a refresh, you can store the same value in ViewState and Session. If the user refreshes a page, it will PostBack using the old ViewState data that does not match your Session value. Once you detect this, you can create a Page that all of your other Pages inherit from with a simple variable to test for whether the user refreshed the browser. This solution requires ViewState to be enabled and a valid Session.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    if (IsPostBack && ViewState[REFRESH_CHECK_GUID] != Session[REFRESH_CHECK_GUID])
    {
        IsRefresh = true;
    }
    Session[REFRESH_CHECK_GUID] = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    ViewState[REFRESH_CHECK_GUID] = Session[REFRESH_CHECK_GUID];
}

/// <summary>
/// True if the last PostBack was caused by a Page refresh.
/// </summary>
public virtual bool IsRefresh
{
    get;
    private set;
}
```

Comment: I've used that example in an app as well, basically adding IsRefresh as a property to all of my base webforms pages.  It works quite well.

Answer (score 3):

In the ideal scenario, a HTTP POST submit that causes a database update would redirect after successful update to a secondary page which informs the user about the success of the operation. If the user tries to go back to the previous page, the browser would prompt the user with a message similar to ""The page cannot be refreshed without resending the information. Click Retry to re-send the information or click cancel to continue". This should suffice as user intimation that refreshing the page will entail duplicate submission. If the update failed, however, the same page would load and allow the user to retry.

Of course, this is not a hard and fast rule and implementations vary. I would greatly recommend taking @edg's suggestion into practice - Your database insertion code should always check duplicacy before applying an insert/update.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to the term "duplicacy". Is that a neologism?

Comment: I wouldn't take the credit for coining the word, because it seems to be in common use (http://www.google.com/search?q=duplicacy), even though I couldn't find a single definition of the word! Good catch, John. Hey, where's my vote?! :P

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have any session (and have cookies enabled) you could use:

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);

    if (IsPostBack && ViewState[REFRESH_CHECK_GUID] != Request.Cookies[REFRESH_CHECK_GUID])
    {
        IsRefresh = true;
    }
    String checkGuid=System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    Response.Cookies[REFRESH_CHECK_GUID] = checkGuid;
    ViewState[REFRESH_CHECK_GUID] = checkGuid;
}

/// <summary>
/// True if the last PostBack was caused by a Page refresh.
/// </summary>
public virtual bool IsRefresh
{
    get;
    private set;
}
```

Comment: this looks like a nice solution in the SharePoint Full Trust implementaiton where using Session is not available by default.

Answer (score 1):

If the application is yours, you need to add code that checks first that the record does not exist before attempting to save it to your database.

Comment: if we want to allow duplication, then what to do?

Comment: Then you do not have a problem anymore, I should think. Atleast not according to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the hidden value that resides in __EVENTTARGET that cannot be set through code.

If you can use Ajax to add your data then this issue can be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Even if we use Ajax for whole form, it gives the same duplicate insert,
but we can try by clearing hiddenfield _EventTaret and change the focus of some other control :)

Answer (score 0):

As David M said above, the best idea is to redirect after the post. The affect of having another server round-trip is pretty minimal, as only the http headers are sent in a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

If you **need** to stay in the same page, then I recommend you redirect the user to a confirmation page where you can then ask the user if they want to insert another record, if so then you redirect them back to the page where they can insert records, this will help prevent the duplicate inserts. Or they can just go to a "main" page if they are done inserting records. This is what I have done in the past when I needed users to be able to "stay" in the same page after an insert.

Answer (score 0):

After insert or update statement is executed you can redirect the user to the same page with

**Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);**