# How to display percentage completion in Ajax updateprogress in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, jquery, updateprogress

**Background:**
I have a long-running query on a button click. Hence, updateprogress is invoked to notify user that process is in progress.
Currently it is displaying a static data i.e a label.

When the long running process is executed, as expected contents of udapteprogress appears in foreground and freezes the remaining content.
i.e.*Report generation is in progress, Please do not close the window*

Now we would like to show percentage completion
i.e. xx% (Ex: 10%) while contents of updateprogress are on foreground

**Code:**
Updateprogress

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <div id="progress">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblProgress" Text="Report generation is in progress, Please do not close the window" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </div>
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

Updatepanel with button

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upExport" UpdateMode="Always" runat="server"> 
                                    <ContentTemplate> 
                                        <asp:Button ID="btnExport" runat="server" Text="Export"
                                            OnClick="btnExport_Click" /> 
                                    </ContentTemplate> 
                                    <Triggers> 
                                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnExport" EventName="Click"/> 
                                    </Triggers> 
                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Server-side function:

```
    protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
    //long running method
}
```

P.S: while the process is executing btnExport_Click and updateprogress is in foreground, i would want it to display % completion.

In my failed attempt, i tried updating a session variable in 'btnExport_Click' method and access it via javascript but unsuccessful

**Update 1:**
I would like to know a way in which i could communicate % value while i am still in long running method, Coz once control exits from long running method. it would be 100% completion and updateprogress will no longer be on foreground.

Thanks for your time:)

Comment: Whay it failed , you can make AJAX call to get the value from Session and update the label on the client side

Comment: @Devesh,Could you please share any link which would help me achieve this.

Comment: Maybe this link will help you :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309264/refreshing-reloading-side-effect-with-asp-net

Comment: @Portekoi, this speaks about Post-Redirect-Get. didnt help me much:(