# GridView adds duplicate row on Page refresh

Tags: asp.net

GridView adds duplicate row on Page refresh--

I am having two methods 1)bindgridview() 2) insertdata()

whenever i am inserting the data through webform and displaying the data in gridview after that when i am refresshing page or press f5 again the duplicate record is inserted can anyone tell me what is the solution for this

where shall is if(!page.ispostback) in pageload event or insert data can anyone tell me,,

Thanx in advance

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743580/page-refresh-causes-duplicate-post-in-asp-net-applications

Comment: I looked up the code and now it should work for you.

Answer (score 5):

A solution I used in the past was to add a time stamp to check if the Postback is a refresh. What I did was add

```
Page_Load()
{
    ...
    Session["CurrentTime"] = Server.UrlEncode(DateTime.Now.ToString());
}
```

and also on

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
   ViewState["CurrentTime"] = Session["CurrentTime"];
}
```

then, when InsertData() was called, I would add a check like this

```
InsertData()
{
     if(ViewState["CurrentTime"].ToString() != Session["CurrentTime"].ToString())
         return;
}
```

EDIT: I looked up the code, and this is the correct way to make it work. Hope I've helped.

Comment: @thinker07 It would be nice if you marked the answer as accepted, so that other users know it works (and I get my happy points as well ;-) )

Comment: @user242375 You should accept this answer so it doesn't appear as unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

if you call the function insertdata() in Page_Load without the condition of Postback it always run the function.

The better is call the insertdata() function on the button click event.

if the buttons is the child of gridview then you can use the RowCommand event of gridview to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I have another way of doing the refresh. In your `Page_Load()` method, do the following:

`GridViewname.Columns.Clear();`

This worked for me, and also works well with AJAX enabled pages.