# button click event automatically fires

Tags: c#, asp.net

My situation is like this i have a asp button inside my user control

```
  <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit"
        Text="Send Notification" class="submit-btn01"   onclick="btnSubmit_Click1" runat="server" />
```

in my browser when I refresh my page, button click event automatically happens.i cant figure out what is wrong with this..

Comment: Have you tried removing `class="submit-bt01"` and double check again ?

Comment: i have already done it..but is of no use..

Comment: Can you check the view source of this button, how its rendering.Also ensure you have not firing this button event handler from jQuery or page_load method.

Comment: i havn't understood it @Deepu can u please explain it

Comment: Is it a submit button? Maybe, after you press refresh button your browser performs a page submitting. Open a new tab in the browser and navigate to your site, does click event fire again?

Comment: for my surprise this thing does not happen the first time i refresh my page.that is if i pressed submit button once and after that when i refresh my page it happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a little vague. It sounds like you have one of the following scenarios:

Scenario A:

1. Load the page by URL
2. Click submit, a refreshed page comes back.
3. Hit F5 on the page and you get a message asking if you want to resubmit the form, and the Submit button action happens again

Scenario B:

1. Load the page by URL
2. Hit F5 on the page and and the Submit button action happens

*For Scenario A;*

if you want to avoid the re-postback, you should do a Response.Redirect() *to the current page* in the btnSubmit_Click1 event handler, as mentioned in more detail here:
[asp.net prevent form submission twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526568/asp-net-prevent-form-submission-twice)

*For Scenario B;*

1. Are you doing any javascript in the page that would cause it to behave differently on each page load?
2. Are you getting to the page by way of a post-back from a different page?
3. Are you doing anything odd/fancy in the page life-cycle on the code-behind side? E.g. CreateChildControls?

...if it's scenario B, and the answer to these are no, then I'm very curious to see what the final cause of the problem is as I can't imagine why a page would behave differently between a load and a reload.

Comment: my situation is accurately as in the Scenario A: thanks for Explaining things for me.

Comment: at my present situation i cant do Response.Redirect. can any one tell me any other ideas

Comment: Can't you do this in your page:?                                   protected override void button_onclick(object sender, EventArgs e) { SendMail(); Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri); }    ...note that the important thing is that you are not redirecting to a new page, you are redirecting to the page you are already on, but the redirect will do a GET and not a POST

Answer (score 1):

Refresh is likely repeating the *last action* that was performed if it was a POST.
Since the last action was to submit the form using your button that is getting replayed.

Comment: @D Stanley I think you are right(it is a POST ) .can you suggest any solution

Comment: It depends on _how_ you want it to behave. Redirecting to a new page is simplest.