# File upload not works after ValidationExpression

Tags: asp.net, regex, file-upload

I have one problem:
I'm using a ValidationExpression in fileupload control, the user muse not upload files like executables or zips, or rars, etc.
So I use a RegularExpressionValidator and it works, users can't upload this kind of files, but if users try to upload a forbidden file, the ValidationExpression works, shows the message on the control, but If the user try again to upload new files that are correct, the fileupload control don't work because the first time the RegularExpressionValidator is activated forbidden the upload:

this is my fileupload control:

```
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="UploadImages" AllowMultiple="true"  />
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="expValUpImg_Ext" runat="server"
                        ControlToValidate="UploadImages" ErrorMessage="Formato invalido"
                        ValidationExpression="/^[^.]+$|\.(?!(js|exe|zip|rar|7z|tar|msi)$)([^.]+$)/" >
                    </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

How can reactivate the upload control, or refresh it for a new validation?

I hope anyone please help me.

best regards

Comment: Perhaps this page might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17982897/fileupload-uploads-undesired-files-on-page-refresh

Comment: Are you sure that good files are not being uploaded? Maybe the problem is just that the error message is not going away?